Input scanning and deletion in real time for pattern recognition
I am using a library called pynput for scanning the keyboard input in real time. I store each character in a list, compress it to a string and detect patterns.
The issue lies in deletion. The scanning happens in real time so the list needs to reflect the current state of what has been typed. Now when I delete in the middle it deletes from the end. How can deletions be reflected in real time?
Currently I am tracking cursor position using a counter, which isn't the most efficient method.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example including a sample input and your desired and observed result.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
